# Find reverse ForeignKey instances of Queryset?

Tags: django

The django documentation is pretty clear on how to look up fields on single instances but what about reverse relationship QuerySet objects.

**Example:**

```
class Author(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(...)

class Book(models.Model)
    title = models.Charfield(...)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, ...)
```

I now create a queryset object:

```
special_books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains="Space")
```

Now, I want to find all authors that belong to special_books. I want to do something like this:

```
special_books.authors.all()
```

Without doing this:

```
authors = []
for book in special_books:
    authors += book.author
```

**Is there a way to do this easily?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the referenced Model name (Book in lowercase) to make your query:

```py
Author.objects.filter(book__title__icontains="Space")
```

If you have a `related_name` defined in your foreignKey :

```
class Book(models.Model)
    title = models.Charfield(...)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

Your queryset would be :

```py
Author.objects.filter(books__title__icontains="Space")
```

Quoting [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) :

> Related managers support field lookups as well. The API automatically follows relationships as far as you need. Use double underscores to separate relationships. This works as many levels deep as you want.

Comment: sorry, I have to resubmit the question. I aked the question wrong. Sorry. But your answer is correct for what I've asked.

Comment: Fantastic, this I didn't know. I didn't know, I could reference the reverse model manager via the related name as a query attribute! Fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the lookup on Author model that [spans relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

```
Author.objects.filter(book__title__icontains="Space")
```

Comment: sorry, I have to resubmit the question. I aked the question wrong. Sorry.

Comment: so answer is the same just other way around, same rules apply

Comment: Thank you for sticking with it! Sorry for the confusion! Your answer is great!